# Updating View Model Before Focus is Lost or How To Restrict Commands While Maintaining Tab Order

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, focus

In WPF, when designing forms, it is common to disable form elements (such as buttons/commands or entire areas) in response to the state of the View Model. This is easily done by having the CanExecute check the various properties on the View Model.

However, this breaks the User Experience when an element is dependent on the element immediately preceding it and the user wants to move focus (either through tab or using the mouse).

Example: Say I have a login form that requires a username and a password. Both fields must be non-empty before the Login button can be pressed. The problem is that the binding for the Password is not updated until focus has been lost, but when that happens the button has not been enabled yet. So focus moves on to the element following that, instead of focusing on the Login button.

This can generally be easily solved by changing the binding to update on PropertyChanged. However, this may not always be a good user experience. In cases of expensive validation, you want to limit how often the user has to wait. Or if an input element has a minimum length and I'm providing visual error notifications, I don't want to warn the user while they are typing.

Is there a better way of solving this problem?

And is there a reason why bindings update **after** focus was lost, instead of at the time focus is about to be lost? Ideally the element would lose focus, the binding would update, then the container would determine what element to focus on next.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55016/discussion-between-jordy-boom-and-sheridan).

Answer (score 1):

You can throttle the execution of updating the BindingSource by setting the `Delay` property on the `Binding` element.

This is useful when you know your validation check is expensive, or if you want to make sure the user has stopped typing before giving them validation results.

Ex.

```
//Delays updating the binding source by 1000 ms
<TextBox Text="{Binding Password, Delay=1000}" />
```